# Performing Left Joins in ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: linq-to-entities

Pre .NET 4.0 - the EF does not support the DefaultIfEmpty() clause.  Is there a better way of performing a left join on a query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just don't use the `join` syntax at all. [It's almost never correct to use `join` in LINQ to Entities](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) (or LINQ to SQL). Use associations instead.